# Unable to click element in SPAN

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code :

```
<td colspan="2">
<a id="Apply" class="ovalbutton" title="Click to get Sensor Statistics" tabindex="4"      value="Get Stats" name="Apply" onclick="ActionButtonClick('Apply','Get Stats');"  style="position:relative; right:-38%;" onselectstart="return false;" readonly="readonly">
     <span>Get Stats</span>
</a>
</td>
```

In Selenium WebDriver, I'm unable to simulate click action on the button. I'm using Eclipse Java.

this is the button that I tried to simulate the click action
http://postimg.org/image/l6v0gh7hl/

```
 WebElement btnReg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains('Register      Sensor')]"));
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(btnReg));
 action.moveToElement(btnReg).build().perform();
 action.click(btnReg).perform();
```

Comment: Please post the Java code you used in Selenium

Comment: Any particular reason why your span is nested within your anchor?  Is there more to the span than what you're showing, because this is valid HTML as of 4.x.

Comment: Thank you for all helps. Finally I managed to solve it. Need to run javascript using JavascriptExecutor to get the result that I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I am able to click on it using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Apply")).click();
```

looks like something is wrong with `ActionButtonClick` method which is invoked on the click event. I just replaced it with simple alert and it did worked.

```
 onclick="javascript:alert('test')"
```